# Java поведение оператора case

Tags: java

```
    char g = 'a';
    switch(g){
        case 'a' :
            System.out.println("a");
        case 'с' :
            System.out.println("b");
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("Default");
    }
```

Почему в консоли выводит "a" и затем "b", если переменная равна символу "a"?

Comment: потому что в первом case нет break

Comment: я имел ввиду, что разве case не делает проверку на следующее за ним значение? Почему case 'c' выполняется, если переменная не равна 'c'?

Comment: потому что так устроен switch-case , в литературе это поведение называется fallthrough, если нет break или return, то выполнятся следующие case, в порядке, в котором они указаны, пока не встретится break или return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char g = 'a';
switch(g){
    case 'a' :
        System.out.println("a");
        break;
    case 'с' :
        System.out.println("b");
        break;
    default :
        System.out.println("Default");
        break;
}
```

Не много поправил ваш код. Программа выводила сразу 2 значения, потому что вы упустили `break;`. Оператор `break;` ставится после каждой проверки условия. Как сказали в комментариях, если нет `break` или `return`, то выполнятся следующие `case`, в порядке, в котором они указаны, пока не встретится `break` или `return`.